# Grouping arrays with different lengths to make a single sentValues() for the spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently I find out which is the biggest array and from it I generate a *`while`* loop and I go around errors with *`try catch`*:

```javascript
function stackoverflow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Ratings Time A');
  var menu = [
    ['Atletico Lanus'],
    ['1795.72'],
    ['Atletico Lanus'],
    ['Independiente Jose Teran'],
    ['2.83 Fair'],
    ['2.77 Fair']
  ];

  //Home Team
  var home_team = [
    ['Fernando Monetti (GK)', '53'],
    ['Braian Aguirre (DF)', '60'],
    ['Nicolas Pasquini (DF)', '57'],
    ['Matias Pérez (DF)', '43'],
    ['Diego Braghieri (DF)', '47'],
    ['M. Gonzalez (MF)', '23'],
    ['Raul Loaiza (MF)', '41'],
    ['Tomas Belmonte (MF)', '62'],
    ['Lautaro Acosta (ST)', '63'],
    ['José Sand (ST)', '52']
  ];

  // Away Team
  var away_team = [
    ['Moisés Ramirez (GK)', '61'],
    ['Richard Schunke (DF)', '68'],
    ['Luis Segovia (DF)', '65'],
    ['Willian Vargas (DF)', '57'],
    ['Mateo Carabajal (DF)', '57'],
    ['Jhoanner Chavez (DF)', '52'],
    ['Fernando Gaibor (MF)', '60'],
    ['Junior Sornoza (MF)', '68'],
    ['Lorenzo Faravelli (MF)', '69'],
    ['Jonathan Bauman (ST)', '73'],
    ['Jaime Ayovi (ST)', '60'],
    ['Joan Lopez (GK)', '19']
  ];

  final_array = [];
  let i = 0;
  let ct = Math.max(menu.length, home_team.length, away_team.length);
  while (i < ct) {
    try {
      var menu_0 = menu[i];
    } catch {
      var menu_0 = '';
    }
    try {
      var home_team_0 = home_team[i][0];
      var home_team_1 = home_team[i][1];
    } catch {
      var home_team_0 = '';
      var home_team_1 = '';
    }
    try {
      var away_team_0 = away_team[i][0];
      var away_team_1 = away_team[i][1];
    } catch {
      var away_team_0 = '';
      var away_team_1 = '';
    }
    final_array.push([
      menu_0,
      home_team_0,
      home_team_1,
      '',
      away_team_0,
      away_team_1,
    ])
    i++;
  }

  sheet.getRange(3, 1, final_array.length, final_array[0].length).setValues(final_array);
}
```

This *`setValues()`* to the spreadsheet is done to generate this result (note that there is an empty column between `home_team` and `away_team`:

[image]

I would like a review on this method that I am using to be able to group the lists in order to generate the correct sequence in the array to define in which column each index will be sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `const` and `let` as needed instead of declaring all variables as `var`. This helps the [javascript engine optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070631/v8-javascript-performance-implications-of-const-let-and-var) the memory and processing of such variables
- Practice `DRY`(Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. You repeat `try...catch` thrice. You can create a function instead and pass different variables like `menu_0` to it.
- In this case however, you can

  - Create a `collection` array( `[menu, home_team, [], away_team];`) with the order of arrays you want concatenated.
  - Create a `output` array with maximum length of all those arrays(`Array(Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length)))`)
  - Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  and  [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to concatenate inner arrays from `collection`

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
function stackoverflowTheMaster() {
  // const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Ratings Time A');
  const menu = [
    ['Atletico Lanus'],
    ['1795.72'],
    ['Atletico Lanus'],
    ['Independiente Jose Teran'],
    ['2.83 Fair'],
    ['2.77 Fair'],
  ];

  //Home Team
  const home_team = [
    ['Fernando Monetti (GK)', '53'],
    ['Braian Aguirre (DF)', '60'],
    ['Nicolas Pasquini (DF)', '57'],
    ['Matias Pérez (DF)', '43'],
    ['Diego Braghieri (DF)', '47'],
    ['M. Gonzalez (MF)', '23'],
    ['Raul Loaiza (MF)', '41'],
    ['Tomas Belmonte (MF)', '62'],
    ['Lautaro Acosta (ST)', '63'],
    ['José Sand (ST)', '52'],
  ];

  // Away Team
  const away_team = [
    ['Moisés Ramirez (GK)', '61'],
    ['Richard Schunke (DF)', '68'],
    ['Luis Segovia (DF)', '65'],
    ['Willian Vargas (DF)', '57'],
    ['Mateo Carabajal (DF)', '57'],
    ['Jhoanner Chavez (DF)', '52'],
    ['Fernando Gaibor (MF)', '60'],
    ['Junior Sornoza (MF)', '68'],
    ['Lorenzo Faravelli (MF)', '69'],
    ['Jonathan Bauman (ST)', '73'],
    ['Jaime Ayovi (ST)', '60'],
    ['Joan Lopez (GK)', '19'],
  ];
  const collection = [menu, home_team, [], away_team];
  const output = Array(Math.max(...collection.map((a) => a.length)))
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => collection.flatMap((a) => a[i]));
  console.log(output);

  // sheet
  //   .getRange(3, 1, final_array.length, final_array[0].length)
  //   .setValues(final_array);
}
stackoverflowTheMaster();
```

```html
   
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->        
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```